# How to modify Filter in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid with its default Filter, and I would like to bring a litte modification.

[image]

In drop down list we have different restrictions, ('Starts with','Contains' etc).
 And what I want is:

1. To set 'selected' for 'Contains' by default
2. On load put focus in input box just under dropdown list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For make some operator default you should just change order in filter options:

```
filterable: {
                        extra: false,
                        operators: {
                            string: {
                                contains: "Contains"
                                eq: "Is equal to",
                                neq: "Is not equal to"
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

And for focus on text field you can use [`filterMenueInit` `Event`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-filterMenuInit). 
It will look like this for your case:

```
filterMenuInit: function(e) {
    var popup = e.container.data("kendoPopup");
    popup.bind("activate", function (e) {
        this.element.find("input").focus();
    });
}
```

First you need to select `KendoWidget` for filter - `kendoPopup`. 
After that you bind function on event which fired after popup is fully load - `activate` event. And in function you update control state as you need.

Comment: The first issue is solved. But second one, `e.container.find("text")` didn't work, I changed it to: `e.container.find("input")`, and it finds me input element, but doesn't want to put focus on it.

Comment: Yes, I wrote example without correct selectors for your specific case. But `e.container.find` can return array of elements. Check what inside and select one what you need to focus. Some docs about focus method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp

Comment: I guess it puts focus on it, later it loses it. To check if it affects something on my input, I did: `textField.val('Hello')`, and it works. I see Hello in input on load. But for focus doesn't seem to be working!

Comment: Yes you right I update my answer now, check it out :)

Comment: Greattttt, works smoothly!!!
If you could explain in few words what you did, would really apreciate it!

Comment: First you need to select KendoWidget for filter - kendoPopup. After that you bind function on event which fired after popup is fully load - activate event. And in function you update control state as you need.